# update-in for sets in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, set

i have a series of items in a set like this:

```
(def my-set
  #{
    {:id "ab" :a 1 :b 2}
    {:id "abc" :a 1 :b 2}
    {:id "abcd" :a 1 :b 2}
  }
)
```

: and I wish to update one of the items something like this :

```
(update-in-set    my-set  :id  "abc"   {:id "abc" :a 6 :b 20})
```

. that would return :

```
  #{
    {:id "ab" :a 1 :b 2}
    {:id "abc" :a 6 :b 20}
    {:id "abcd" :a 1 :b 2}
  }
```

: Is there any Clojure built in function or other easy way to do this?

### Update

In the end I did this:

```
(defn update-in-set    [my-set  key  value  new-record]
  (merge (clojure.set/select #(not= (get % key) value) my-set ) new-record)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if you shouldn't be using a map rather than a set here, with id as the key. Then what you want to do could be easily performed with `assoc`.

You are having problems as sets don't really have the idea of updating values - each item is unique and either present or not - so what you need to do is remove the old value and add a new one. This could be done a little easier with `conj` and `disj` I think:

```
(conj (disj #{'a 'b 'c} 'a) 'e)
```

Which would remove 'a and add 'e. This assumes you have some way of getting the complete item from the "key".